# Проблема вывода нулевого указателя на char

Tags: c++, char, вывод, null

Столкнулся с непонятным мне поведением.

Есть код в мейне :

```
char* pC = NULL;
std::cout << pC;
std::cout << "Any output";
```

И, что не понятно, он выводит ничего. Весь вывод, следуемый после вывода pC (указатель типа char*, указывающий на NULL), уже не выводится никак.
Интересно, что если использовать указатель типа int*, то все работает корректно.

Почему так с char* = NULL происходит? Извините, если вопрос глупый для вас.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Этот же вопрос на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019454/why-does-stdcout-output-disappear-completely-after-null-is-sent-to-it)

**СТРОГОЕ ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ**

Вывод `char* = nullptr` при помощи `cout` вызывает *неопределенное поведение*. Это нарушение стандарта языка, и это делать просто нельзя.

В случае `libstdc`, это "Неопределенное поведение" становится вполне определенным, события разворачиваются вот так:

`iostreams` пытается интерпретировать `char*` как строку. А когда вы ему суете ноль, он портиться - выставляет себе бит ошибки и перестает работать.

Небольшой эксперимент на [ideone](http://ideone.com/9r7y9m):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main() 
{
    char* pC = nullptr;         //использование nullptr 
                                //вместо NULL - использование
                                //современного стандарта языка
    std::cout << pC;

    // выводим статус потока, будет "0"
    printf(" goodbit state is %d\n",\
    std::cout.rdstate() == std::ios_base::goodbit);



    std::cout << "Any output";  // не сработает - cout сломан

    std::cout.clear();          //сбрасываем ошибку

    std::cout << "Any output";  //теперь вывод работает
    return 0;
}
```

**Однако, полагаться на это не стоит.** Правильное решение - не пытаться выводить `nullptr`.

Если же надо вывести значение указателя на строку, приведите его тип к чему-то другому

```
   std::cout << static_cast<void*>(pC) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Исчерпывающе.

Answer (score 5):

Тут случается [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Потому как в описании оператора английским по белому [написано](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/):

> If s does not point to a null terminated character sequence, it causes
>   undefined behavior.

Очевидно, что NULL-указатель не является "null terminated character sequence".